# Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], UIKit//UITableView.m

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, crash

My application crashes with the message that appears in the title of this thread. Assertion failure in the UITableView.m. Moreover there is the following message in the debugging window in the Xcode.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert section
>   2 but there are only 2 sections after the update'

This is strange, because the number of sections before and after the update seems to be 3. I control the number of sections here:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  
{
    if (editMode)
    {
        if ( [device typeA]) {

            if ( [device typeB])
                return 1;
            else
                return 2;


        }
```

Hint: I want to "hide" the last section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are returning 2 as the number of sections even after you added one, of course iOS thinks there is something wrong. You should hied a section differently, e.g. by setting it's header height to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to insert an additional (third) section, but your code reflects the possible change only for having 1 or 2 sections.

Instead of hardcoding the number of sections, you should try reading them from your dataSource to make sure the number is always consistent.